# How close are inverses of sub-matrices of positive definite matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{p\times p}$ are two positive definite matrices, and let $S\subset \{1,2,\ldots,p\}$ be a subset of indices. I suspect that the following is true, and was wondering if someone can point me to a reference or a proof: 
$$\|(A_S)^{-1} - (B_S)^{-1}\|_{\rm max} \lesssim \left\| A^{-1} - B^{-1} \right\|_{\rm max},$$
where $\lesssim$ is hiding constants that do not depend on $p$, $A_S$ is the submatrix of $A$ indexed by the elements in $S$, and $\left\|  \right\|_{\rm max}$ is the element-wise absolute maximum of a matrix.